# Is the group law for SO(2n, R) encoded in so(2n,R)?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, orthogonal-matrices, orthogonal-groups

Note that this is a partial duplicate of my [math.stackexchange question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4335505/convergence-of-bch-formula-for-real-special-orthogonal-group-lie-algebra?noredirect=1#comment9044229_4335505). In this post I am asking something slightly broader. Note that I am a mathematical physicist and *not* a representation theorist / Lie algebrist / Lie group researcher so I apologise for any mistakes and would gratefully accept any corrections!

It is well known that the group law for a Lie group is *locally* (i.e. in some neighborhood around the identity) encoded in the Lie algebra. This encoding can be expressed by the Baker-Campbell-Haussdorf-Dynkin formula and the fact that the BCH formula does not generally converge essentially expresses the failure of the Lie algebra to capture the group law globally. However I do not know anything about where/whether the BCH formula converges for the special orthogonal group.

Because of some physics problem that would be off-topic for this forum I am interested in expressing the product of two $\mathrm{SO}(2n,R)$ matrices exclusively in terms of the Lie algebra. In other words I want a procedure that will take two $ 2n\times 2n $ real, skew-symmetric matrices $A$ and $B$ (elements of $\mathfrak{so}(2n,R))$ and find a third $C$ such that

\begin{align}
    e^A e^B = e^C.
\end{align}

My intuition is that if $C$ is going to be obtained from $A$ and $B$ in any way it is probably going to require BCH in some form, but I would be very happy if I was wrong about that.

I expect that a sensible "first step" would be to first block-diagonalise $A$ and $B$ and use periodicity to make the eigenvalues small (in magnitude). Doing this it is possible (WLOG) to assume $A$ and $B$ have eigenvalues in the ingerval $[-i\pi, i\pi)$, for example.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#Questions_of_convergence and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_map_(Lie_theory)#Surjectivity_of_the_exponential might help.

Comment: @AlexM. Its definitely relevant that the exponential is surjective for $\mathrm{SO}(2n, \mathbb{R})$ (if this was not true I definitely wouldn't be asking the question). I couldn't find anything on the wki page for the BCH formula that answered my questions about the special orthogonal case.

Comment: From the BCH Wikipedia page that I linked to above: *"Concretely, if working with a matrix Lie algebra and $\| \cdot \|$ is a given submultiplicative norm, convergence is guaranteed if $\| X \| + \| Y \| < \ln \sqrt 2$"*.

Comment: Or this: http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.laa.2003.09.010.

Comment: @AlexM. That I've read the wiki page and that article recently. The condition given is not necessary for convergence, and I was hoping that a much weaker condition suffices for matrices in the special orthogonal Lie algebra. The couterexamples given in the wiki page and the article are such that there does not exist a matrix in the Lie algebra that exponentiates to the product of the two exponentials. This case never happens for the special orthogonal group/algebra since the exponential is surjective. I don't know if there are cases of non-convergence that are not of this form.

Comment: You are ready to accept the assumption that the eigenvalues are bounded by $\pi$. If instead you are satisfied with $\ln \sqrt[4] 2$ instead of $\pi$, then the theorem given above works: identify $SO(2n, \mathbb R)$ with a subspace of $\mathbb C ^{2n}$, and take $\| \cdot \|$ to be the usual norm on this space; in this very case, $\| A \| \le \rho(A) < \ln \sqrt[4] 2$, whence everything follows ($\rho(A)$ being the spectral radius of $A$). For details: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius#Matrices, the case of Hermitian matrices, which $SO$ matrices are a particular case of.

Comment: @AlexM. I am not satisfied with $\ln{\sqrt[4]{2}}$, unless it is the case that every $\mathrm{SO}(2n, \mathbb{R})$ is the exponential of an $\mathfrak{so}(2n,\mathbb{R})$ matrix satisfying that bound, which I think is not true (or unless a counterexample exists showing that this bound is necessary to ensure convergence in this case).